# Ember.js: How to access nested view instances

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Say I'm defining nested views, like so ([code example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tx3NP/)):

```
App.ParentView = Ember.View.extend({
    ChildView: Ember.View.extend({ ... }),
    method: function() {
        this.get('ChildView') // => this is the class, not the instance :(
    }
});​

{{#view App.ParentView}}
    {{#view ChildView}}
        ...
    {{/view}}
{{/view}}
```

I'd like to avoid binding a lot of attributes between the parent view and the child view. Rather, I'd like to do something like `this.getPath('ChildView.foo')`. But `this.get('ChildView')` returns the class that I created with Ember.View.extend, not the instance, so I cannot access the attributes.

Is there a canonical way to access the current instance of a child view from inside a method of the parent view?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can pass a view the `viewName` variable and access the view through the parent that way.

See http://jsfiddle.net/Tx3NP/5/

```
{{#view App.ParentView}}
  {{#view childView viewName="childViewInstance"}}
     ...
  {{/view}}
{{/view}}
console.log(this.get('childViewInstance.value'));
```

Or you can do as @weltraumpirat recommends and access the `this.get('childViews')` array.

Comment: Seems to me the `viewName` binding is what the ember.js authors intended for you to use, `_childViews` looks private IMO. And giving the view an id doesn't help if you have multiple instances of it.

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful. I've adopted a convention of calling my classes `ChildView` (capitalized) and using `viewName="childView"` (non-capitalized) for the instance names. This makes it reasonably non-confusing.

Comment: @Bradley, in your example, is there a difference between ```getPath``` and ```get```, if ```this``` refers to the parent view?

Comment: @Sherwin `getPath` has been deprecated since this answer was posted, `get` is the appropriate method these days.

Comment: This method works great, but I can't find it documented anywhere. Undocumented features have a tendency to go away without warning. If someone finds it documented, please post the link.

Comment: contacted developers and was provided this link: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_view. This appears to be use the developers intended, and should be safe to use

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `_childViews` array:

```
 console.log( this._childViews[0].get('value') );
```

*or* you can give your view an id and simply use jQuery to access the corresponding HTML element.

```
{{#view childView id="childView"}}

console.log( Em.$('#childView')[0].value );
```

Comment: I'm morally opposed to pulling application data out of the DOM like in your second example. ;-) But good pointer with `_childViews`, even if it's private.

Comment: Is there an equivalent of _childViews which only returns non-virtual views?

Answer (score 0):

It's actually quite simple.

As of 2.10.0, if you're inside a component and need to find a nested component, simply search through:

```
  const id = 'my-specific-id-im-looking-for',
    views = this.get('childViews');

  let count = views.length;

  if (count) {
    while (--count) {
      if (views[count].get('elementId') === id) {
        // this is your view. do stuff with it, call methods on it, whatevs;
        break;
      }
    }    
  }
```

If you're prior to this, try using the component's method `forEachChildView`